Why does this light switch have three black wires connected?
I am changing out an old light switch in our condo. It controls an outlet inside the room, as well as one directly on the other side of it, on an exterior wall.
I'm using a Decora push click paddle light switch. It has two black terminals and a ground on it.
I'm confused by the existing switch having three black wires, one back stabbed and two sharing a screw terminal. Also the switch has two grounds.
Did they do this instead of pigtailing? If so, how should I clean this up to use a new switch and do it the right way?
I know that no one likes the back stabs, but I was curious about these switches. They feel pretty solid.


Seems to me like the backstab is the hot going "in" and the looped wire is the two loads going "out."  I'd think you could simply connect the backstabbed wire to one terminal on your new switch, and the looped wire to the other terminal.

Possibly you must switch to pigtails, possibly you may.  Depends on the switch.
Most new outlets and switches except the 99-cent ones have rear-entry terminals that are not "backstabs" in the traditional sense.   If they have provision for multiple wires per terminal, so long as the wires are all the same size and construction (solid or stranded) you can do what's done in your photo, but properly.   You can pig tail or not, up to you.   (The two rear-entry ports per terminal go under a proper screw-down connector with room designed for two wires.  One screw fastens both wires so if they are not identical, one of them easily ends up poorly connected.)
If by "push click" you mean Leviton Edge switches, I think they do not have provision for multiple wires at all. You must pig tail.
You should also tie the ground wires together and pig tail to the switch. That's a good practice always.  I think you have a plastic box there so that's that.  If it's metal there's more to do.

Okay, this makes sense. I realize now that the ground that's tied in there is from a light switch in the same box, it controls an exterior light. Not sure if that makes a difference in terms of where to ground to generally.

Generally, the grounds in a box should be arranged so that a device like a switch can be replaced without interrupting ground path between other things.   So: 1) If the box is metal, the ground with the  cable supplying power should be connected to the box.  2) All grounds entering from the back of the box should be nutted together, with enough pigtails added for the devices in this box 3) The pigtails attached to the devices.  When you swap a switch or outlet, OTHER BOXES and all their attached devices and appliances remain grounded.

okay interesting. So as it stands, when I disconnect the switch in question, the remaining switch is no longer grounded. So, what should exist is, a ground coming to each switch from the grounds that are pigtailed in the back of the box. Gotcha.

And essentially, to swap this switch to the new style decora edge, I take the two black wires that are in the screw terminal, and wire nut them together with a pig tail, and put that in one of the black terminals on the edge switch, and then keep the backstabbed black wire as is. And then make a new pigtails for the grounds to go into both new switches.

Exactly.  And in general, if you are working on a switch with two black wires on one terminal, you don't have to know exactly what the second one feeds.  You may know now that it's just one switch, but in general, it might go on to supply arbitrary other switches and outlets, and if you disconnect their grounds, they are all one tiny step closer to being dangerous.  Any one other fault in one of them could make them deadly.
